If we try to avoid reading the Haftorah for Parshas K'doshim, why was it chosen as the Haftorah?
We go to great lengths to avoid reading the Haftorah for Parshas Kedoshim because of how harsh it is. In years where Eretz Yisrael and Chutz La'aretz are reading different Parshios as a result of a second day of Yom Tov celebrated only in Chutz La'aretz, we wait until Matos Maasei to catch up even though there are several double parsha opportunities earlier. And rather than reading this Haftorah in Yerushalayim when the schedule falls out in a way where we would read the Haftorah for K'doshim (like 2024), we read the one for Acharei Mos again. My question is, if we're going to such great lengths to avoid reading this Haftorah, why was it instituted as the Haftorah?

The question is anachronistic. When they instituted the haftara no one avoided reading it.

@DoubleAA So when did the avoiding start happening?

@Curious mostly in the last ~200 years or so https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/142302/759 This question is just a reason to not hold like these newfangled "avoiders" and do as Jews did for ages.

Today I learned about avoidism

Tough love may be necessary in small doses, on rare occasions.
